# HTML response support for Restler 3 APIs

Tags: php, restler

I need to support different response formats like JSON and HTML, so far this was good with JSON response formats, now I tried to support HTML response from my APIs and facing issues.

I need to return JSON response from some of the APIs and HTML response from some APIs, but all the APIs(methods) present in same class.

If I add both JSON and HTML in supported formats list then all APIs are returning HTML response only, not sure how to manage this situation.

`$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'HtmlFormat');`

This is the code block I am using to set JSON and HTML in supported formats list, anybody please let me know how to handle this scenario.

**index.php**

```
use Luracast\Restler\Defaults;  
use Luracast\Restler\Filter\RateLimit;  
use Luracast\Restler\Format\UploadFormat;  
use Luracast\Restler\Format\HtmlFormat;  
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;  

require_once 'vendor/restler.php';  
require_once('config.php');    

Defaults::$throttle = 20;  
Defaults::$cacheDirectory = PLAY_API_CACHE_DIR;

// Setup restler  
$r = new Restler();  
$r->addAPIClass('test');  
$r->addAPIClass('Resources');   
$r->addFilterClass('RateLimit');  
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'UploadFormat', 'HtmlFormat');  
$r->handle();
```

**test.php**

```
require_once 'BaseHandler.php';

class test extends BaseHandler {

    // Initialize API class attributes
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
    * Request the breakdown,by category, of a user's synced data.
    * 
    * @param string $auth_token SSO Authentication Token
    *
    * @url GET getStorageUsage
    */
    public function getStorageUsage($auth_token = '') {

        // Required parameters checkup
        if (!$auth_token && isset($_SESSION['play_auth_token'])) $auth_token = $_SESSION['play_auth_token'];
        if (!$auth_token  )    return PlayErrorCodes::throwParameterMissingError();

        // Get a breakdown,by category, of a user's synced data using Sync API call
        return $this->callAPI('sync', 'getStorageUsage', array('auth_token' => $auth_token));    
    }

    /**
    * Requests the full HTML document representing a users data graphically
    * 
    * @param string $auth_token SSO Authentication Token
    * @param string $client Name of the client requesting the widget.  android is the only acceptable and default value.
    * @param string $path Path of the resource to display.  Defaults to '/'
    *
    * @url GET getWidget
    * @view getWidgetView
    */
    public function getWidget($auth_token = '',$client = '',$path = '') {
        // Required parameters checkup
        if (!$auth_token && isset($_SESSION['play_auth_token'])) $auth_token = $_SESSION['play_auth_token'];
        if (!$auth_token)    return PlayErrorCodes::throwParameterMissingError();

        // Get the full HTML document representing a users data graphically using Sync API call
        $this->resDecodeFlag = false;
        return $this->callAPI('sync', 'getWidget', array('auth_token' => $auth_token, 'client' => $client, 'path' => $path)); 
    }

}
```

Here I need to return JSON response for 'getStorageUsage' and HTML response for 'getWidget'.

References I have gone through are:
http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_013_html/readme.html
https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/tree/master/public/examples/_013_html#html-format

Thanks in advance... Siva.

Comment: What did you try so far, where is your code? We cannot review code we cannot read.. What error do you get, where do you seem to fail?

Comment: @Luceos: updated my question with code blocks. Not getting any error here, after setting up the HtmlFormat support all APIs are returning HTML response.

Comment: How are you doing calls. Restler identifies return format based on Accept Header you send. So if you are calling on your webservice from the browser it will return HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Luceos rightly pointed out Browser sends accept headers that always prefer HTML

To overcome this situation you can always request these resources with the respective extension

- `getStorageUsage.json`
- `getWidget.html`

If a specific resource needs to be always in a specific format you can do the following

```
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('MyApiClass');
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'UploadFormat');
$r->setOverridingFormats('HtmlFormat');
$r->handle();
```

Then on your getWidget method add `@format` comment to specify `HtmlFormat` as shown below

```
/**
* Requests the full HTML document representing a users data graphically
* 
* @param string $auth_token SSO Authentication Token
* @param string $client Name of the client requesting the widget.  android is the only acceptable and default value.
* @param string $path Path of the resource to display.  Defaults to '/'
*
* @url GET getWidget
* @view getWidgetView
* @format HtmlFormat
*/
public function getWidget($auth_token = '', $client = '', $path = '') {
    //your logic comes here
}
```